# Magento remove protype from theme everywhere?

Tags: magento, themes, prototype

I try to remove the prototype and other default js crapp from magento.

Using this works for cms pages and the homepage:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <cms_page>
        <reference name="root">
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/prototype.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ccard.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/validation.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/builder.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/effects.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/controls.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/slider.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/js.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/form.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/menu.js</name></action>
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/translate.js</name></action>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
</layout>
```

but how to make this template wide ? so those js will not be in the theme at all anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Default prototype location is in:

```
app/design/frontend/package/theme/layout/page.xml
```

Line containing:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
```

In the package/theme folder you're using please comment this line out or delete it and flush caches.

Note that without prototype one page checkout will be broken.

Comment: I noticed that, is there a documented solution for 1 page checkout using Jquery instead?

Comment: We implemented a completely custom checkout with jquery

Comment: is it possible to share your solution maybe ?

Comment: Same problem is , that I'm having issues with the discount code. Seems a lot of prototype is used in Magento. Also try to fix that. Magento is really a b***ch to cleanup and customize. Preferable not use magento at all but for this project it was sadly required.

Comment: Sadly the solution implemented was 100s of man hours of coding time and 100s of files to displace vanilla checkout. I would suggest purchasing a commercial jquery one page checkout/multiple page checkout solution. Something like this ( I'm not affiliated ) http://www.mage-world.com/magento-one-step-checkout-extension.html